# Pegar o valor de um input e retornar alerta

Tags: javascript, formulário

Estou tentando retornar um valor de um input que recebe o valor de uma variável  que também recebe o valor de uma pequena equação, porém não estou conseguindo.

O código está assim:

```
function calcularimc() {
    var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');

    var quilos = +formulario.quilos.value;
    var metros = +formulario.metros.value;
    var centimetros = +formulario.centimetros.value;

    var altura = (metros * 100 + centimetros)/100;

    var imc = quilos / (altura * altura);

        if (imc <= 25) {
        alert(ok);
    }

    formulario.imc.value = imc.toFixed(2);

}
]
```

obs: quando eu retiro a parte do `if`, ele volta a fazer o cálculo e apresentar o resultado.

Pessoal, o primeiro erro era que eu não havia deixado uma string entre aspas.
Segundo, é que eu precisava colocar várias condições if e else if. Ficou assim:

```
<form id="formulario">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Cálculo do IMC</legend>

        <label for="quilos">Quilos:</label>
        <input type="text" name="quilos" />

        <label for="metros">Metros:</label>
        <input type="text" name="metros" />

        <label for="centimetros">Centímetros:</label>
        <input type="text" name="centimetros" />

        <label  for="imc">IMC:</label>
        <input  type="text" name="imc" disabled="disabled" />

    <a href="#" onclick="calcularimc();">calcular</a>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

function calcularimc() {
    var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');

```
var quilos = +formulario.quilos.value;
var metros = +formulario.metros.value;
var centimetros = +formulario.centimetros.value;

var altura = (metros * 100 + centimetros)/100;

var imc = quilos / (altura * altura);

if (imc <= 18.5 ) {
    alert('Abaixo do peso!');
} else if (imc > 18.6 && imc < 24.9) {
    alert('Peso ideal');
} else if (imc >= 25 && imc < 29.9){
    alert('Levemente acima');
} else if (imc > 30 && imc < 34.9) {
    alert('Obesidade grau 1');
} else if (imc > 35 && imc < 39.9) {
    alert('Obesidade grau 2');
} else if (imc > 40) {
    alert('Obesidade grau 3');
}

formulario.imc.value = imc.toFixed(2);
```

}

Comment: A sua questão está um pouco confusa. `alert(ok)` só irá funcionar se `ok` for uma variavel. Se é suposto aparecer como texto tem de levar aspas simples ou duplas. Qual é exatamente a dificuldade que está a encontrar?

Comment: Grande Isac, me desculpe,cara, realmente minha pergunta ficou confusa, pois sou bem iniciante. Realmente faltaram apenas as aspas na string. Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no `alert`:

```
alert(ok);
```

Onde `ok` não é uma variável. O correto seria colocá-lo entre aspas, simples ou duplas:

`alert("ok");` ou `alert('ok');`

Ao chegar nesse pronto seu script não prossegue porque dá erro de *variável não definida*.

**Complementando**, quando você coloca uma palavra no código sem aspas, o código supõe que ela seja um objeto (variável, função...) e não um texto. Objetos devem ser declarados, do contrário resulta em erro.

Comment: Show de bola, era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

A resposta anterior está correta, mas aparentemente está com um erro no cálculo do IMC, dê uma olhada nisso. Como já tinha começado a responder a pergunta vou publicar um código que tinha feito baseado no seu.

```js
function calcularimc() {
   var quilos = parseInt(document.getElementById("quilos").value);
   var metros = parseInt(document.getElementById("metros").value);
   var centimetros = parseInt(document.getElementById("centimetros").value);

   var altura = (metros*100 + centimetros)/100;
   var imc = quilos / (altura * altura);
   console.log(imc);
   if(imc <= 18.5){
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = 'Abaixo do peso';
   }else if(imc <= 24.9){
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = 'Peso normal';
   }else if(imc <= 29.9){
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = 'Peso em excesso';
   }else if(imc > 29.9){
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = 'Obesidade';
   }
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
  <input type="text" id="quilos" placeholder="Quilos">
  <input type="text" id="metros" placeholder="Metros">
  <input type="text" id="centimetros" placeholder="Centímetros">
  <button type="button" onclick="calcularimc()">Calcular</button>
  <br><br>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Phelipe, obrigado! Eu realmente esqueci as aspas. Problemas de iniciante hehe

Comment: Ahh, Phelipe. No caso, eu adicionei um else if depois pra mostrar um novo alerta pra um peso diferente. Deu certo, porém não consigo adicionar outro. Sabe me dizer o problema?

Comment: Haron, fiz uma edição na minha resposta arrumando o código para fazer o cálculo corretamente e já mostrar na tela o valor. Não estava calculando corretamente pois estava entendendo centímetros como string e estava concatenando com a altura, e não somando.

Comment: Phelipe, é que mostrar o resultado do cálculo não é realmente o objetivo do meu alerta, mas sim pegar a informação do valor calculado, fazer um comparativo e informar o indivíduo se ele esta acima do peso ou não, dependendo do nível. Quer ver o código todo pra poder entender melhor?

Comment: Editei mais uma vez, colocando as condições, mas se não é dessa forma que você queria, basta pegar a variável imc e fazer o que seu projeto precisa com ela.